# Error building sasl for python 3.5.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, hive, sasl

To connect to Hive using Python 3.5.1
I was able to install pyhs2, thrift and Pyhive.
But during installation of sasl which is needed by phyhs2, got this error.

```
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\sasl
    copying sasl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\sasl
    running egg_info
    writing dependency_links to sasl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to sasl.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing sasl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing requirements to sasl.egg-info\requires.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying sasl\saslwrapper.cpp -> build\lib.win32-3.5\sasl
    copying sasl\saslwrapper.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\sasl
    copying sasl\saslwrapper.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.5\sasl
    running build_ext
    building 'sasl.saslwrapper' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\mmt6168\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -
u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\mmt6168\\AppData\\Local\\
Temp\\pip-build-qvb3rz0y\\sasl\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open',
 open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --rec
ord C:\Users\mmt6168\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-irc4xc0f-record\install-record.txt -
-single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Use
rs\mmt6168\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qvb3rz0y\sasl\
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is struggling to find a C++ compiler that matches the compiler that was used to compile your version of Python for Windows. For Python 3.5 on Windows, you need Visual C++ 14.0. A quick fix for this version is to install [Visual Studio Community 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx).

Otherwise, see here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.0_standalone:_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_Build_Tools_2015_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.29